# Target Android SDK 27 in a Xamarin.Android app

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm unable to target Android SDK 27 in my Xamarin.Android app; in target frameworks the newest sdk listed is 8.0 and when I try and add the latest Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat which depends on SDK 27 I get the following error:

> You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

I've installed SDK 27 using the SDK Manager and my environment looks like this:

Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac
Version 7.3.3 (build 23)
Installation UUID: d672627e-j4b7-49bc-8b23-bb090208deXX
Runtime:
    Mono 5.4.1.7 (2017-06/e66d9abbb27) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Package version: 504010007

Xamarin.Android
Version: 8.1.5.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/mark/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
        4.4   (API level 19)
        5.0   (API level 21)
        5.1   (API level 22)
        6.0   (API level 23)
        7.0   (API level 24)
        7.1   (API level 25)
        8.0   (API level 26)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 27.0.1
SDK Build Tools Version: 27.0.3

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. To target SDK 27 you need to install from the beta channel so that you get Xamarin.Android 8.2. I think its a little confusing the Xamarin.Android 8.1 doesn't correspond to Android 8.1 (SDK 27) but I guess thats not the convention.

In Visual Studio for Mac when you check for Updates you have an option to pick beta or alpha in the upper left corner.